# No carga imagen gif

Tags: html5

Tengo este codigo

```
<div id="cargando"><img src="/images/822.gif"/>
  <h5>  Ejecutando...</h5>
</div>
```

carga cualquier imagen que no tenga el formato gif, que tengo que hacer para que cargue gif?

El gif lo descargue de aqui https://icons8.com/preloaders/en/circular

Comment: Acabo de descargar ese mismo gif de la misma página, funciona haciendo pruebas con el gif en local y funciona también con un gif desde URL

Comment: Tienes algún estilo asignado al id **cargando**? Puede ser que alguna propiedad este deshabilitando el _gif_

Comment: Prueba a cambiar la extensión a mayúsculas: .GIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probé exactamente con la misma imagen ya sea de manera local y con una url y, me ha funcionado, pero al probar con tu código, me ha surgido el mismo problema, así que lo modifiqué un poco, este es tu código:

```
<div id="cargando"><img src="/images/822.gif"/>
  <h5>  Ejecutando...</h5>
</div>
```

Pero he realizado una pequeña modificación:

He creado la misma carpeta y he sacado la primera barra **`/`** que está dentro del **`src`** del tag de **`img`** dejándolo como lo muestra a continuación:

```
<div id="cargando"><img src="images/822.gif"/>
  <h5>  Ejecutando...</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: En conclusión, el problema estaba en cómo se estaba dando una ruta absoluta a la imagen, en vez de una relativa.

Answer (score 0):

Como Puedes Ver en el ejemplo tu codigo funciona perfectamente bien

```html
<div id="cargando"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/200px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"/>
  <h5>  Ejecutando...</h5>
</div>
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/200px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif" alt="Funny image">
```